# Update list of Master object with list of Sub object

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8

I have `Deal` object and it has `subDeals` (list of `Deal`), I need to update the `subDeals`. `DealDTO` object has list of `subCodes` so I to need find the `Deal` object for each `subCodes` and update the `subDeals` into `Deal`.

Here is the `Deal` class:

```
public class Deal {
    String code;
    BigDecimal price;
    List<Deal> subDeals;
    public Deal(String code, BigDecimal price) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.price = price;
        this.subDeals = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    // geteer setter
    public void addSubDeal(Deal subDeal) {
        subDeals.add(subDeal);
    }
}
```

Here is the `DealDTO` class

```
public class DealDTO {
    private String masterCode;
    private List<String> subCodes;
    public DealDTO(String masterCode, List<String> subCodes) {
        super();
        this.masterCode = masterCode;
        this.subCodes = subCodes;
    }
    // geteer setter
}
```

Below is the approach I am trying to but it is not working:

```
List<Deal> masterDeals =
            Arrays.asList(
                new Deal("ABC",new BigDecimal(5)),
                new Deal("DEF",new BigDecimal(10)),
                new Deal("GHI",new BigDecimal(15))
                );

    List<DealDTO> dealDTOs =
            Arrays.asList(
                new DealDTO("ABC", Arrays.asList("JKL")),
                new DealDTO("DEF", Arrays.asList("JKL", "ABC")),
                new DealDTO("GHI", Arrays.asList("MNO"))
                );

DealDTO dealDTO = null;

for(Deal masterDeal : masterDeals) {
    // get DealDTO which matches with masterDeal's code
    dealDTO = dealDTOs.stream()
            .filter(dto -> dto.getMasterCode().equals(masterDeal.getCode()))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
    // if subCodes are present then traverse through it and get the Deal object from masterDeals list and update the masterDeal
    if(dealDTO.getSubCodes() != null && !dealDTO.getSubCodes().isEmpty()) {
        dealDTO.getSubCodes().stream().forEach( code -> {
            for(Deal deal : masterDeals) {
                if(deal.getCode().equals(code)) {
                    masterDeal.addSubDeal(deal);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // subDeals has been added so persist masterDeal here
}
masterDeals.forEach(System.out::println);  // throws java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Lists are huge so I wanted to make sure that I follow the right approach to update the `subDeals`.

Comment: Looks like you have circular dependencies between your deals and subdeals. That is the reason you are getting a stack overflow. Do you expect this dependencies in the actual data? In that case you need to have some mechanism of keeping track whether a deal is visited or not.

Comment: @KDM Yes, `Deal` has `subDeals` and `subDeals` is in fact list of `Deal`

Comment: In your test data, "Abc" has "Def" as a subdeal which in turn has "Abc" has a subdeal. This is what I meant by circular dependency of data (not the structure). Is your real data also like this?

Comment: @KDM thanks for pointing that out. Data is huge so I am not sure whether it has circular dependency. Would you suggest/pointer a good approach for this logic?

Comment: @KDM I am sure that `subDeals` is list of `Deal` so it could create circular dependency, is not it?

Comment: Self referential structure doesn't mean that The data could have circular dependency. Depending on whether the data can have circular ￼dependencies you need to create the logic.

Comment: @KDM I got it what you are saying, I have checked few data and it seems there is not circular dependency between them. I have updated my question with correct data and now it is working as expected, does it mean my written logic was correct but the data I was using for testing purpose was circular dependent. You are awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things that you can do for improving the performance since you are mentioning that the lists are huge.

1. Use a Map to keep the deals instead of a List. Given a code you should be able to retrieve a deal fast.
2. If possible, let the Deal also save only `codes` for subdeals. Provide a getter `List<Deal> getSubDeals` that creates the list when needed and returns.

Comment: accepting as an answer since it helped me to identify the problems, thanks